# Visual studio 2019 "Disable project code" no longer visible

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

I wrongly clicked on "Disable project code" in the Xaml designer.
Then my code throws exceptions which is expected.

Problem is that visual studio does not show any of the icons anymore for this Xaml file.
Other Xaml file in VS do show the items.

Anyone an idea on how to force VS to show the icon again.

Attached a view on the bar I'm talking about.

[image: V]

Kind regards
Bram

Answer (score 2):

Confirm, I don't have it also (Version 16.4.3). And the worst part is that I don't see any way to downgrade to previous version. Hope they fix this asap.